# Update fileset using ant dynamically

Tags: ant, properties, fileset

I would like to create a jar file dynamically depending on selected java modules
Here is the part of the ant script which does that. 
`<property name="modules.selected" value="A,C,F" />` 
`<for list="${modules.selected}" param="module">` 
    `<sequential>`  
        `<echo>Module chosen ${basedir}/@{module}/src</echo>`
        `<copy todir="${build.dir.src}" overwrite="true">`
            `<fileset dir="${basedir}/@{module}/src">`
                `<include name="**/*.${src.valid.exts}" />`
            
`</fileset>`
        `</copy>`
    `</sequential>`
`</for>`

In the above script I am selecting a module and then constructing a directory and copying all the modules present in the directory to a location (build/src). 
But I really dont like the logic mentioned above would like to change to include all the required modules in a `fileset` and use the populated `fileset` to copy.
Here is the logic I am looking for 
`<fileset id="required-modules" dir="${basedir}/@{module}/src">`
    `<for list="${modules.selected}" param="module">`
        `<sequential>`
            `<echo>Module chosen ${basedir}/@{module}/src</echo>`
            `<include name="**/*.${src.valid.exts}" />`
        `</sequential>`
    `</for>`
`</fileset>`

`<copy todir="${build.dir.src}" overwrite="true">`
    `<fileset refid="required-modules" />`
`</copy>`

Could anyone update the above script to make it work.

Comment: Why do you want to copy the Java source files in the first place? Why not compile them in their original location and build the jar you require from the classes compiled? And why build a single jar rather than, say, jar per module?

Comment: I need specific modules (A,C,F) of my projects to be part of the `jar` rather than all the modules(A,B,C,D,E,F) . So I would dynamically change the modules in the property and then create a jar and then use newly created Jar.

Comment: do you have a pattern for A,C,F ? just wondering if a regex would work.